# jstl as Spring 3 email template

Tags: spring, email, templates, jstl

I'm building an standard web application.
For generating view i'm using jstl.

Withih this application i need to send some emails. 
I was looking for a email temlate, and i found Velocity.

And now i thinking, do i really need a Velocity or i can use jstl for email templates. Maybe jstl would be the best solution ?

Or maybe you have your own solutions for email templates ?

If there is an possibility to use jstl, how to use it ?

Do you have any examples or tutorials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Velocity as it is easy, light, lots of support on the web and you are not limited to what you can do with your templates.

Here is an implementation of Velocity with Spring:
[velocity null point exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522321/velocity-null-point-exception/14522835#14522835)

For the template, just use HTML with keywords `${keyword}`

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <h3>Hi ${userName}, this is an email template with HTML!</h3>

    <div>
        Your email address is <a href="mailto:${emailAddress}">${emailAddress}</a>.
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use loops, inject beans etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [**Thymeleaf**](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) as it supports Rich HTML e-mail Template .
The detailed sample example is available here. [**Spring3 MVC+ Thymeleaf**](http://www.thymeleaf.org/springmail.html)

**Features :**

- Expressions in Spring EL.
- Flow control: iterations, conditionals, ...
- Utility functions: date/number formatting, dealing with lists,
  arrays...
- Easy i18n, integrated with our application's Spring
  internationalization infrastructure.
- Natural templating: our email templates can be static prototypes,
  written by UI designers.