# Spring mail with Velocity Engine

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc, velocity

I am trying to write a class that sends email by using spring mail and velocity template engine. I want to use email templates because there is lots of email types in my system. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522321/velocity-null-point-exception) post, but there is something wrong with `MimeMessagePreparator`. It overrides `prepare` method and `prepare` method use `javax.mail` as parameter. I have add maven dependency of java mail api. This time, it overrided current spring mail api. If you have ever used spring mail and velocity template together, could you please help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some code please.

Comment: @Ved, i have used same code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522321/velocity-null-point-exception

Comment: I have added maven dependency and re-imported spring mail classes and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javax.mail
        mail
        1.4

after import, it overrides spring mail api. I have re-added spring mail classes to project and it worked. Spring mail classes are the ones `org.springframework.mail.javamail.*`

Thanks